# LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

Tags: latex, paragraph

\paragraph{* bla bla bla:
\begin{itemize}[label=\textendash]
\item bla 1
\item bla 2
\end{itemize}
}

Answer (score 1):

You are abusing `\paragraph`. This is only for the headline itself, not for the whole text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{bla bla bla:} \begin{itemize} \item bla 1 \item bla 2 \end{itemize} 


\end{document}
```